# "Required" validation message remains after removal of [Required] attribute MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I had a `[Required]` attribute in one of my view model's properties:

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* Required")] // this has now been removed
public int QuoteQuantity { get; set; }
```

I removed the `[Required]`, but I still get this validation message that prevents me from submitting.

In the view I have these lines:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", value = "1" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuoteQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

When I leave this empty and submit I get this validation error:

> The QuoteQuantity field is required.

I should mention that I have built the solution repeatedly, closed and reopened VS, and still I keep getting this validation error even though the current code is this:

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
public int QuoteQuantity { get; set; }
```

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: It's because `QuoteQuantity` is an `int`, and cannot be null, so your validation still requires it. I've posted an answer below :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because your `QuoteQuantity` is an `int`, which is currently not `Nullable`, so when you're trying to validate, the field cannot be empty because it does not allow `null`s.

2 ways of getting round this:

- Set your `QuoteQuantity` int as `int?` (`Nullable int`)

or

- Use a different property to accept the value as a `string`, and in your `get` for the `QuoteQuantity`, use an `int.TryParse` to see if the string can convert to an `int`. *You would need some sort of check in place, though to see if it falls within your min/max range - if you have one*

**Example**:

***First suggestion:***

```
public int? QuoteQuantity { get; set; }
```

***Second suggestion:*** (returns `0`, if the string is empty/null or not a valid `int`)

```
public int QuoteQuantity
{
    get 
    {
        int qty = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(QuoteQuantityAsString))
        {
            int.TryParse(QuoteQuantityAsString, out qty);
        }
        return qty;
    }
}

public string QuoteQuantityAsString { get; set; }
// You will then need to use the
// QuoteQuantityAsString property in your View, instead
```

I would suggest the first option, and make sure you do `null` checks around where you're using the `QuoteQuantity` :)

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

In the fairness of giving various options, I've just thought of another way (probably better than suggestion 2). *Either way, I think suggestion 1 is still the best way.*

In order to return validation only if the user *does* input something into your "Quote Quantity" string input on the view:

***View:***

- In the View, add a text input, that allows the user to input the quantity (or not, as might be the case) and use this in place of your current `QuoteQuantity`  elements
- Give it an `id` + `name` of something like `quoteQty`
- Add a ValidationFor, like before, but give it the `quoteQty` name as the first argument

***Controller:***

- In your controller `POST` method, accept another param of `string quoteQty` (so that this maps to the same as the `name` from your View). This will get populated from your HttpPost
- *Before* your `(ModelState.IsValid)` check, try and parse the `quoteQty` as an `int`; if not, add a `ModelError` for `quoteQty`, with a message
- Then, your model will return a validation error and be displayed on the page as desired.
- *Downside is, this can't be validated client-side so the server will have to return the error*

Like this:

```
public ActionResult SendQuote(Model yourmodel,
                              string quoteQty)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(quoteQty))
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(quoteQty, out yourmodel.QuoteQuantity))
        {
            // If the TryParse fails and returns false
            // Add a model error. Element name, then message.
            ModelState.AddModelError("quoteQty",
                                     "Whoops!");
        }
    }
    ...
    // Then do your ModelState.IsValid check and other stuffs
}
```

And just use the original property

```
public int QuoteQuantity { get; set; }
```

in your model. *An `int`'s default value will be `0` if you never set it. If the `TryParse` fails, it sets the value to `0`, too*